# using phones back button to exit from webview

Tags: android, button, webview, back

The phone back button works in the webview,but when I want to exit from the Webview to the application this didn't do anything.
I put a button that go back to the application but I did't that remain that way.

JAVA:

```
package com.wiralss.adb;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
 public class about extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 WebView webView;

  final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.instagrem);
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
Button B123=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1235);
B123.setOnClickListener(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
    {
        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

        if(progress == 100)
            activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    }
});


webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,    String failingUrl)
    {
        // Handle the error

    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

  }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button1235:
        Intent B = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(B);
    break;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onBackPressed (){

    if (webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();       
    }
    else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        webView.goBack();


        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1235"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="580px"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another question.
To remove the button I need to delete?:

```
Button B123=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
B123.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.button1:
        Intent B = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(B);
    break;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Tank you very much.

Comment: why the call to `webView.isFocused()`?

Comment: what happens if you remove it?

Comment: Check my answer ... it should help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the call to `super.onBackPressed()` as you are controlling the finishing of your activity yourself.

Equally, you don't really need the `webView.isFocused()` method call.

You can rewrite your `onBackPressed` method to read like this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();       
    }  else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

I'm not too sure on your motives for including your `button1235` Button, is that something you are wanting to remove?

Comment: It doesn't work. I am wanting to remove the button,the button return to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `onKeyDown` method implementation as the way you implement it will case `onBackPressed` to never be called. `onBackPressed` should be only:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

To remove the button it's enough to make it gone, but first of all you need to declare it as class member:

```
private Button B123;
```

and initialize it as you do in `onCreate`:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
B123 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1235);
B123.setOnClickListener(this);
```

To make it gone:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1235:
        B123.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Intent B = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(B);
        break;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I would change the layout as well as you're getting some lint errors since you're using `px` instead of `dp`. The whole layout can be improved.