# How can I provide quick exit from WebView that has back history traversal?

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation

Several SO questions cover the topic of how to wire up a `WebView` to have the "back" button traverse browser history. An [Android developer doc page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-webviews) answers that question well. We have an app that uses the recommended method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise defer to system default behavior.
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And that works fine. But the doc page also cautions,

> Be careful when using this mechanism with highly dynamic web pages
>   that can grow a large history. Pages that generate an extensive
>   history, such as those that make frequent changes to the document
>   hash, may make it tedious for users to get out of your activity.

Our client has confirmed that this is a problem: When following over a dozen successive links within a `WebView`, getting back out to the previous (parent) activity *is* tedious, especially because you have to wait between taps of the back button for the WebView to refresh.

Unfortunately the developer doc page doesn't suggest a workaround for this situation.

One possibility is to **[use the "up" button](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html#ancestral-navigation)** in the toolbar/appBar/actionBar to exit the WebView.

My concern with that is that the "up" button normally looks like a backward-pointing arrow or chevron, very similar to the "back" button (identical to the "back" arrow in some browsers). So then we'd have an "up" button in the toolbar and the Android "back" button, looking very similar and doing something different. That would seem confusing to the user.

Is there a better way to provide "exit" navigation from a WebView besides the "back" button?

(Not a duplicate: [using phones back button to exit from webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594339/using-phones-back-button-to-exit-from-webview) asks how to get the "back" button to exit the WebView *only after there's no more history to traverse back over*.)

Answer (score 1):

> One possibility is to use the "up" button in the toolbar/appBar/actionBar to exit the WebView.

What else would you have in the toolbar? What would it do?

Usually every screen that is not the root has a home (up) button in the toolbar that closes the screen again. That's how most Android apps work.

> My concern with that is that the "up" button normally looks like a backward-pointing arrow or chevron, very similar in concept to the "back" button (identical to the "back" arrow in some browsers). So then we'd have an "up" button in the toolbar and the Android "back" button, looking very similar and doing something different. Is that a recipe for confusing the user?

That's Android and if you do it that way you follow the platform guidelines. As mentioned above, that arrow in the toolbar is in almost every app and navigates away from the current screen, whether its called home, back, up, or something else.
But you're right, back and up gets confused a lot.

An alternative is to opt for the *close* style. Replace the default arrow by an ✖ and its action *closes the current screen* should be evident.

While I prefer the Up arrow, the ✖ is a valid alternative, especially if you pop some WebView for additional content and want a strong indicator on how to close it again.

> Is there a better way to provide "exit" navigation from a WebView besides the "back" button?

Nope. You could try asking on UX Stack Exchange, but you already have 2 platform standards—namely back and up—that can and should be used for navigation.

Anything else that you might come up with would be "new" and unique to your app, but of course you could just add a "Close Screen" button.

---

*tl;dr* If you don't like the Up Arrow in your toolbar use an ✖ as a close icon.

Comment: I hate how one must try not to use "back" when describing the up functionality to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was kind of thinking along these lines (yes it's confusing but those are the platform guidelines), and the confirmation is helpful.